# Unable to find other user in look up

Tags: administration

What could be the reason that I am  unable to find other user in look up when I am trying to change the owner of account or any object ?

Answer (score 1):

Most probable reason is because that user does not have minimum read access on account or other object, thus cannot own the record.

As mentioned here:

> You can give ownership of a record to another user as long as that user has at least Read permission for the type of record being transferred.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.account_owner.htm&type=5

And as @sfdcfox mentioned, it also depends on user sharing
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.security_sharing_users_concept.htm&type=5

Comment: It's also possible the user can't see other users because of [User Sharing](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.security_sharing_users_concept.htm&type=5).

Comment: @sfdcfox that's right, thanks